# sed replace text in-between two strings

Tags: awk, sed

I want to replace the host id in number of files and the host id is different in each file, so I have to replace the content between the tags `<hostid>` and `</hostid>`, each file has only one `<hostid>` line

```
<hostid>71342-231VMKDK-47WW-03dMV6</hostid>
```

to

```
 <hostid>xxxx-yyyyy-zzz-uuu-bb</hostid>
```

I did try something like below which didn't work

```
sed -i "" -e :a -e 's/\(hostid>[X]*\)[^X]\(.*<\)/\1\something\</;ta'
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put to solve your own problem in your post and let us know then.

Comment: I did try my level best but I'm not good with sed

Comment: Not an issue, we do encourage all users to add their efforts either wrong or right that is not an issue, I did add 1 answer let me know if that is helpful, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed '/hostid/s/>.*</>xxxx-yyyyy-zzz-uuu-b</'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself along with taking backup of Input_file then change `sed` to `sed  -i.bak ...`.